# Javascript: Class definition using Websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a basic question about class definition in JavaScript. Let me explain my problem, here is my class (this is a simplified version for the sake of clarity):

```js
var RemoteCursor = function(canvas_id) {
    this.ws_sendjoingroup = function() {
      console.log('Dummy log just for debug');
    }
    this.ws_cursor_onopen = function() {
      console.log('ws_cursor_on open: (debug)');
      this.ws_sendjoingroup();
    }
    this.ws_start_remote_cursor = function() {
        this.ws_remote_cursor = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/ws');
        this.ws_remote_cursor.onopen = this.ws_cursor_onopen;
    }
}
```

I call this class inside my HTML page like this:

```js
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var cursor1 = new RemoteCursor("usimage_cursor");
        cursor1.ws_start_remote_cursor();
    }
</script>
```

But when the `onopen` callback fires, inside the function `ws_cursor_onopen` the context is different, `this` have nothing defined and I got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.ws_sendjoingroup is not a function!
>
> The typeof(this.ws_sendjoingroup) is undefined

How can I pass the function inside my instance of `RemoteCursor` as the callback for the `onopen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), it helps lock the value of *this*. Otherwise you can structure it a bit differently;

```js
var RemoteCursor = function(canvas_id) {
  this.ws_sendjoingroup = ws_sendjoingroup;
  this.ws_cursor_onopen = ws_cursor_onopen;
  this.ws_start_remote_cursor = ws_start_remote_cursor.bind(this);


  function ws_sendjoingroup() {
    console.log('Dummy log just for debug');
  }

  function ws_cursor_onopen() {
    console.log('ws_cursor_on open: (debug)');
    ws_sendjoingroup();
  }

  function ws_start_remote_cursor() {
    this.ws_remote_cursor = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/ws');
    this.ws_remote_cursor.onopen = this.ws_cursor_onopen;
  }
}
```

Also, be very aware that using inheritance and OOP programming in JavaScript usually ends poorly and is a somewhat frowned upon practice by more experienced developers. You can learn more about this with D. Crockford's wonderful talk, The Better Parts [here](https://vimeo.com/97419177).

Comment: Thanks @sgarcia.dev. It's working with your suggestion. I also defined the: `this.ws_cursor_onopen = ws_cursor_onopen.bind(this)`

Comment: Great @Bulha. Please mark it as correct answer if it's correct so other people can stop checking this question thinking you still need an answer.